# How can I dynamically connect to different databases with Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working with WinForms and .NET 4.0, using EF 6 with code first.

I need to offer the possibility to connect to a MySQL or a SQL Server DB. For the moment I use different connection strings in the XML `app.config` file and I change the name in the `DBContext` class. How can I make that work dynamically instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//first DbContext
namespace MultiDataContextMigrations.Models
{
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
 public DataContext()
 : base("DefaultConnection")
 {

 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
 //TODO:Define mapping
 }

 public DbSet Users { get; set; }
 public DbSet Orders { get; set; }
}
}
//second DbContext
namespace MultiDataContextMigrations.Models
{
public class UserDataContext : DbContext
{
 public UserDataContext():base("DefaultConnection")
 {
 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
 //TODO:Define mapping
 }

 public DbSet Users { get; set; }
 public DbSet Roles { get; set; }
}
}
```

Check this Link
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html